# What is the signficance of the Prince of Persia delaying the Archangel Michael coming to Daniels aid?

Tags: exegesis, daniel

A writer on Rumor mill news .com recently posted the idea that the Prince of Persia is a substitute (Satanic) god that some Christians worship as God and become deluded in the process.  I cannot at this stage see any way to support this reasoning so I ask:  who exactly does the Prince of Persia represent in a spiritual sense today?  Is it a reference to a historical individual powerful enough to prevent the ongoing work of an archangel in history only, or is there a contemporary meaning also?

Comment: Welcome to Christianity Stack. Your question would be improved by giving the Biblical reference so people can actually find the account you speak of. Please take the Christianity Stack Tour to help improve your question: :  https://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour  This is how we are different to other sites: https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites/1809#1809

Comment: Which Christian denominations do you seek answers from? Please read this article: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I would suggest that this question, if focused on a single text of scripture, might be better suited to [SE-Bible Hermeneutics](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions).

Comment: I believe this question is based on Daniel 10:13. If the real question here is asking “who exactly does the Prince of Persia represent in a spiritual sense today” then it must be aimed at specific Christian denominations in order to avoid people giving personal opinions.

Comment: This question may also embrace other scriptures, e.g. Daniel 12:1 which speaks of Michael, the great prince, who will arise during the end times.  Whose interpretation of these past and future events from Daniel is being sought here?

Comment: Can you add a link about the Prince of Persia being a substitute god.....

Comment: I found the link to The Rumor Mill News web site, but unable to get anything on the Prince of Persia, Michael the Archangel, Daniel or a substitute god.  Waste of time: https://www.rumormillnews.com/cgi-bin/forum.cgi?#128592

Answer (score 1):

I have quoted this answer partly from *St. Thomas Aquinas' Summa Theology* (1, 113, 8) and the *Ignatius Catholic Study Bible*. For me" this makes sense.

**I hope it may be of help:**

> "Prince: An angel who has spiritual oversight and influence over an
>   earthly nation. Reference is made in Daniel to the angelic patrons of
>   Persia (10:13), Greece (10:20), and Israel (12:1). Jewish tradition
>   traces this idea to the Greek LXX translation of Deut 32:8, which
>   states that nations are divided "according to the number of the angels
>   of God" (Deut 32:8 LXX). Christian tradition also teaches that God
>   exercises his providential government over nations through the
>   ministry of angels. They serve as helpers and protectors who are
>   tasked with preserving some knowledge of God and his truth among those
>   who are ignorant of supernatural revelation (e.g. St. Clement of
>   Alexandria, Stromata 7, 2; St Basil, Against Eunomius 3, 1)."
>
> "On the contrary, It is written (Daniel 10:13): "The prince of the
>   kingdom of the Persians resisted me one and twenty days." But this
>   prince of the Persians was the angel deputed to the guardianship of
>   the kingdom of the Persians. Therefore one good angel resists the
>   others; and thus there is strife among them.
>
> I answer that, The raising of this question is occasioned by this
>   passage of Daniel. Jerome explains it by saying that the prince of the
>   kingdom of the Persians is the angel who opposed the setting free of
>   the people of Israel, for whom Daniel was praying, his prayers being
>   offered to God by Gabriel. And this resistance of his may have been
>   caused by some prince of the demons having led the Jewish captives in
>   Persia into sin; which sin was an impediment to the efficacy of the
>   prayer which Daniel put up for that same people.
>
> But according to Gregory (Moral. xvii), the prince of the kingdom of
>   Persia was a good angel appointed to the guardianship of that kingdom.
>   To see therefore how one angel can be said to resist another, we must
>   note that the Divine judgments in regard to various kingdoms and
>   various men are executed by the angels. Now in their actions, the
>   angels are ruled by the Divine decree. But it happens at times in
>   various kingdoms or various men there are contrary merits or demerits,
>   so that one of them is subject to or placed over another. As to what
>   is the ordering of Divine wisdom on such matters, the angels cannot
>   know it unless God reveal it to them: and so they need to consult
>   Divine wisdom thereupon. Wherefore forasmuch as they consult the
>   Divine will concerning various contrary and opposing merits, they are
>   said to resist one another: not that their wills are in opposition,
>   since they are all of one mind as to the fulfillment of the Divine
>   decree; but that the things about which they seek knowledge are in
>   opposition."

**Kind regards, have a nice day!**

Comment: Thanks for providing an external source. It would be great if you, in addition, provide either a summary or commentary on it to actually answer the question.
Thanks for your contribution to the site and hope you will stick around!